# Replicate from master-master setup

Tags: mysql, replication

I have MySQL Master-Master replication on 2 servers.

I want to replicate to another slave server.

When I configure the slave to replicate from `master1`, only data added on `master1` is replicated.   When I added a record on `master2`, the record is replicated to `master1` but not replicated to the slave.

Any idea how to solve this?

- m1

  - `server_id = 1`
  - `log_slave_updates = OFF`
- m2

  - `server_id = 23`
  - `log_slave_updates = OFF`
- s3

  - `server_id = 21`
  - `log_slave_updates = OFF`

Comment: Please run `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'server_id';` for all three servers and post them in your question.

Comment: Please run `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'log_slave_updates';` and post that in the question as well.

Comment: please find info above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## The Problem

The server option [`log_slave_updates`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_log-slave-updates) needs to be enabled on both m1 and m2

## The Solution

Please add the following in /etc/my.cnf on both m1 and m2

```
[mysqld]
log_slave_updates
```

then run this on both m1 and m2

```
service mysql restart
```

## The Reason

Let's use your example above

- `m1` is Master of `m2`
- `m1` is Master of `s3`
- `m2` is Master of `m1`

Here is what happens when you run `INSERT INTO mydb.mytable ...` on `m1`

- `m2` executes `INSERT`
- `m2` records `INSERT` into the current binary log along with server_id=23
- `m1` retrieves `INSERT` from `m2` via I/O Thread
- `m1` records `INSERT` via I/O Thread into lastest relay log
- `m1` retrieves `INSERT` from relay log via SQL Thread and examines its server_id
- `m1` sees that the server_id of the `INSERT` is 23 which is not the same as `m1`'s server_id (1)
- `m1` executes `INSERT`

OK, all well and good. But, why doesn't `s3` get to receive anything? Because `log_slave_updates` is not enabled, `m1` does not save the `INSERT` and the original server_id posting the `INSERT` into its own binary logs.

If `log_slave_updates` was enabled on `m1`, now follow along your example and let's see what should happen:

- `m2` executes `INSERT`
- `m2` records `INSERT` into the current binary log along with server_id=23
- `m1` retrieves `INSERT` from `m2` via I/O Thread
- `m1` records `INSERT` via I/O Thread into lastest relay log
- `m1` retrieves `INSERT` from relay log via SQL Thread and examines its server_id
- `m1` sees that the server_id of the `INSERT` is 23 which is not the same as `m1`'s server_id (1)
- `m1` executes `INSERT`
- `m1` records `INSERT` into the current binary log along with server_id=23
- `s3` retrieves `INSERT` from `m1` via I/O Thread
- `s3` records `INSERT` via I/O Thread into lastest relay log
- `s3` retrieves `INSERT` from relay log via SQL Thread and examines its server_id
- `s3` sees that the server_id of the `INSERT` is 23 which is not the same as `s3`'s server_id (21)
- `s3` executes `INSERT`

This fully explains why `s3` never sees anything from `m2`